# The Super Fast Karma - Covid 19

Tags: karma

Recently i have visited various charities clubs/monastery backup by quite a huge religion community to help out my dad due to covid infection. They are doing well in many areas in term of good deed but i noticed the below. The club may influence others on social media of the below where information can be spread massively and rapidly. If you google the below on any religion, then you may find quite an information.

1. Not following simple standard operating procedure and influence others to do so. i.e. no wearing mask, no social distance, etc. Some would say they already infected and immune to virus so mask is not required or religion massive gathering without adhere any standard operating procedure.
2. Spreading false speech without proof such as the efficacy of the vaccine. i.e. Vaccine is bio-weapon and many died due to the vaccine.
3. Spreading false speech without proof or information without clinical trial such as usage of some medicine/drug that able to cure Covid and avoid taking vaccine or even hospitalization or avoid seek for professional medical help.

Q1) Isn't all of these not just the false speech but against the Buddhism #1 precept ? It's not only killing one but it's might rapidly lead to a massive killing either intentionally or unintentionally ?

Q2) Isn't the action above might rapidly commit all the below as Sotapanna ? All merits may suddenly gone?

> actions that are not committed
>
> A [sotāpanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot%C4%81panna) will not commit six wrong actions:[31]
>
> ```
> Murdering one's own mother.
> Murdering one's own father.
> Murdering an arahant.
> Maliciously injuring the Buddha to the point of drawing blood.
> Deliberately creating a schism in the monastic community.
> ```

Admin Please remove this post if found inappropriate. Translate please: Namo Buddhaya.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What could hunt after good householder if he would let go of bad thoughts, demands, claims and deeds? Yet as long as not seeing ones own delusion, caught in a fault, dwelling in painful states, it's of course difficult. Especially if having disregarded holly ones, that closes up all further development.

Good if good householder let's go of RED very quick and in time.

Comment: well, I move to a place with no or minimum covid impact for healing. Back to ur answer to let go all quick in time. If a person is coughing then you ask the person dont cough would it b possible? Some sharing here too https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-toxic-positivity-5093958

Comment: Nobody, aside of to much little RED, forces good householder to stay next of what he does not like. Why demand? Help yourself first means learn to sacrifice, give... yourself first. Not the usual way, wanting others to do this and give that. So now: hurry up. Red gets hotter and hotter.

Comment: let me ask u ques. If someone in severe pain like losing close one or during funeral session or someone just loss the job then u say this word above ? Did u read my my link provided above ? Please continue in the buddhism chat area n tag me if u wish to continue

Comment: If searching for release, yes. If after RED, possible no need to talk further. (and Links: usually not if not dhammic) Good householder seeks after what? Aside, if able to let go of red, always open [here](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?action=forum). No wishes.

Answer (score 0):

False speech is harmful, also when the TV does it.

Comment: is not from TV but experience myself especially certain religion club. Well i believe not all cities like that. probably only few cities. I dont watch TV too much by the way, as well as political and news recently. only as necessary.